# Separating JavaScript from HTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to separate my JavaScript from my HTML, but it doesn't seem to want to work. Here is the combined code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = 100;
var height = 200;

function Ball(){
    // random radius
    this.radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-5+1))+5;

    // random x and y
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(width-this.radius+1))+this.radius;
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(width-this.radius+1))+this.radius;

    // random direction, +1 or -1
    this.dx = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) * 2 - 1;
    this.dy = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) * 2 - 1;

    //random colour, r, g or b
    var rcol = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    this.col = rcol==0 ? "red" :
               rcol==1 ? "blue" : "green";
}

// create an array of balls
numBalls = 10;
var balls = new Array(numBalls);
for(i= 0 ; i < numBalls ; i++){
   balls[i] = new Ball();
}

// draw the balls on the canvas
function draw(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  // check if supported
  if(canvas.getContext){

    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";

    // draw each ball
    for(i = 0; i < numBalls ; i++){
      var ball = balls[i];
      ctx.fillStyle=ball.col;
      ctx.beginPath();

      // check bounds
      // change direction if hitting border
      if(ball.x<=ball.radius ||
         ball.x >= (width-ball.radius)){
        ball.dx *= -1;
      }
      if(ball.y<=ball.radius ||
         ball.y >= (height-ball.radius)){
        ball.dy *= -1;
      }

      // move ball
      ball.x += ball.dx;
      ball.y += ball.dy;

      // draw it
      ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  else{
    //canvas not supported
  }
}

// calls draw every 10 millis
function bounce(){
    setInterval(draw, 10);
}
</script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="200" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px" onclick="bounce()">
Canvas not supported.</canvas>
```

But when I separate it into separate html and javascript files like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>NodeJS, Socket.IO</title>
    <!-- reference to the JQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- our javascript file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
    <!-- our css file -->

</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="200" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px">
Canvas not supported.</canvas>


</html>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var width = 100;
var height = 200;

function Ball(){
    // random radius
    this.radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-5+1))+5;

    // random x and y
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(width-this.radius+1))+this.radius;
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(width-this.radius+1))+this.radius;

    // random direction, +1 or -1
    this.dx = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) * 2 - 1;
    this.dy = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) * 2 - 1;

    //random colour, r, g or b
    var rcol = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    this.col = rcol==0 ? "red" :
               rcol==1 ? "blue" : "green";
}

// create an array of balls
numBalls = 10;
var balls = new Array(numBalls);
for(i= 0 ; i < numBalls ; i++){
   balls[i] = new Ball();
}

// draw the balls on the canvas
function draw(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  // check if supported
  if(canvas.getContext){

    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";

    // draw each ball
    for(i = 0; i < numBalls ; i++){
      var ball = balls[i];
      ctx.fillStyle=ball.col;
      ctx.beginPath();

      // check bounds
      // change direction if hitting border
      if(ball.x<=ball.radius ||
         ball.x >= (width-ball.radius)){
        ball.dx *= -1;
      }
      if(ball.y<=ball.radius ||
         ball.y >= (height-ball.radius)){
        ball.dy *= -1;
      }

      // move ball
      ball.x += ball.dx;
      ball.y += ball.dy;

      // draw it
      ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  else{
    //canvas not supported
  }
}

// calls draw every 10 millis
function bounce(){
    setInterval(draw, 10);
}

});
```

It doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where is you js file ? I mean the directory .

Comment: Can you check the console? Press `f12` is you're in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that you used to have the canvas defined like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="200" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px"
 onclick="bounce()">
Canvas not supported.</canvas>
```

And now it's defined like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="200" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px">
Canvas not supported.</canvas>
```

Notice that `onclick="bounce()"` is missing from your new HTML file. That's not a problem! It's actually better not to attach event handlers inline. To make your `script.js` file work with the new HTML, change it so that the first few lines look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myCanvas').click(bounce);

var width = 100;
var height = 200;
```

Actually, it would be even better to define the functions `Ball()`, `draw()` and `bounce()` outside the `$(document).ready()` function. Then you would write this:

```
var width = 100,
    height = 200,
    numBalls = 10,
    balls;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myCanvas').click(bounce);

  // create an array of balls
  balls = new Array(numBalls);
  for(i = 0 ; i < numBalls ; i++){
     balls[i] = new Ball();
  }

});
```

Here is a snippet containing the whole JavaScript file revised as I suggest:

```js
var width = 100,
    height = 200,
    numBalls = 10,
    balls;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myCanvas').click(bounce);

  // create an array of balls
  balls = new Array(numBalls);
  for(i = 0 ; i < numBalls ; i++){
     balls[i] = new Ball();
  }

});

function Ball(){
    // random radius
    this.radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*(10-5+1))+5;

    // random x and y
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(width-this.radius+1))+this.radius;
    this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(width-this.radius+1))+this.radius;

    // random direction, +1 or -1
    this.dx = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) * 2 - 1;
    this.dy = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) * 2 - 1;

    //random colour, r, g or b
    var rcol = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    this.col = rcol==0 ? "red" :
               rcol==1 ? "blue" : "green";
}

// draw the balls on the canvas
function draw(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  // check if supported
  if(canvas.getContext){

    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";

    // draw each ball
    for(i = 0; i < numBalls ; i++){
      var ball = balls[i];
      ctx.fillStyle=ball.col;
      ctx.beginPath();

      // check bounds
      // change direction if hitting border
      if(ball.x<=ball.radius ||
         ball.x >= (width-ball.radius)){
        ball.dx *= -1;
      }
      if(ball.y<=ball.radius ||
         ball.y >= (height-ball.radius)){
        ball.dy *= -1;
      }

      // move ball
      ball.x += ball.dx;
      ball.y += ball.dy;
      
      // draw it
      ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  else{
    //canvas not supported
  }
}

// calls draw every 10 millis
function bounce(){
    setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="200" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px"> Canvas not supported.</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. If I wanted to change the click to onload, how would I do that?

Comment: So you want the balls to start bouncing as soon as the page loads? Just replace the line `$('#myCanvas').click(bounce);` with `bounce()`.

Comment: @UXWill Would you please press the button to accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your js file : `document.getElementById ("myCanvas").addEventListener ("click", bounce, false);`
 and remove `onclick="bounce()"` in your canevas tag if you left it in.

Also, you forgot the `</body>` before `</html>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you wrapped all your code in `$(document).ready`. If you didn't need it with the inline script, you should be good without it also when using the external script.